# Changing values on a werkzeug request object

Tags: python, immutability, werkzeug

I have a request object that comes from werkzeug. I want to change a value on this request object. This is not possible because werkzeug request objects are immutable. I understand this design decision, but I need to change a value. How do I do this?

```
>>> request
<Request 'http://localhost:5000/new' [POST]>
>>> request.method
'POST'
>>> request.method = 'GET'
*** AttributeError: read only property
```

I tried doing a `deepcopy`, but the resulting copy is immutable also. I guess I could just create my own mock object and fill in the values manually, but that is my last resort solution. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I came up with:

```
def make_duplicate_request(request):
    """
    Since werkzeug request objects are immutable, this is needed to create an
    identical request object with mutable values
    """
    class Req(object):
        method = 'GET'
        path = ''
        headers = []
        args = []
    r = Req()
    r.path = request.path
    r.headers = request.headers
    r.is_xhr = request.is_xhr
    r.args = request.args
    return r
```

Maybe no the most elegant solution, but it works.