# Change/Replace immutable request object in Flask

Tags: python, oauth, flask, immutability, werkzeug

Currently I am working on an Oauthlib-Flask implementation for a non-REST API. But I have two scenarios where I want to change/add a value of the flask request object. Since it is immutable this doesn't come with ease. I tried making a duplicate as it is suggested in [Changing values on a werkzeug request object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784477/changing-values-on-a-werkzeug-request-object). But since the `@oauth.authorize_handler` uses the given request object I would have to replace it, which resolves in an `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'request' referenced before assignment` error. Here is my sample code (it is a part of the implicit grant):

```
@app.route('/oauth/authorize', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login
@oauth.authorize_handler
def authorize(*args, **kwargs):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        client_id = kwargs.get('client_id')
        client = Client.query.filter_by(client_id=client_id).first()
        kwargs['client'] = client
        return render_template('authorize.html', **kwargs)

    r = make_duplicate_request(request)
    #Change/add values of r
    request = r
    return True
```

Am I doing something wrong or is there another possibility to change the request object?

Thanks for your help!

Update:
The code above describes the situation where I want to pass information to the tokensetter function. This could be done with a global variable, but I wanted to avoid that.

In my signup routine the client sends a request like this to the API:

```
params_signup = {
    "schemas":["urn:scim:schemas:core:2.0:User"],
    "expireIn":3600,
    "username":"test@web.de",
    "password":"123",
    "access_token":"",
    "externalId":"tmeinhardt",
    "grant_type":"password",
    "client_id":"1",           
    "params":{
        "age":"20-30",
        "gender":"m",
        }
   }
```

I need the `grant_type` and `client_id` part only for the tokenhandler and wanted to add it manually to the request object. But since this object is immutable...

Comment: But `oauth.authorize_handler` will access the *context global* `request` **before** your method runs. Due to the nature of how Flask [handles the request context](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/reqcontext/) you cannot simply rebind the global name either.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do that requires you to alter the request, in the first place? You can replace specific objects on the request itself, for example.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes, the oauth.authorize_handler accesses the variable before. but my function is executed before the part where my changes should come into effect

Comment: Please do tell us what problem you are trying to solve; this has all the hallmarks of an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Here I need a variable which I use in my @login function later in my tokensetter function. but meanwhile the request object is changed. And in my signup routine I want to avoid sending the needed oauth parameters and add them manually in my routine and pass them to the handler.

Comment: That's not a very clear description. Can you update your question and add that? Are you simply trying to pass information to your tokensetter function? Can't that information not be stored in the `g` global?

Answer (score 2):

Writing this for those who will come across this and are trying to implement an OAuth flow.

**Don't use decorators use middleware instead**

I believe you should handle this in a middleware. In the middleware, you can set the authorization property of the 2nd parameter of the **call** function which contains the current wsgi app environment variables you have passed in your **init** function.
Look at code below:

```
def __init__(self, app):
    self.app = app

def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
    cookie = Request(environ).cookies.get('access_token')
    if cookie is not None:
        environ['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']='Bearer '+cookie
    return self.app(environ, start_response)
```

Comment: A problem with this, from what I can see, is that if you need to access the form body this way (using `Request(environ).form`), it actually wipes out the form object from being read in the future. So you can't use the form body to populate headers...

Answer (score 0):

you can create a new request and splat the headers into a new dict of an HttpRequest (eg. Authlib's HttpRequest)

```py
from flask import request as _req
from authlib.oauth2.rfc6749 import HttpRequest

request = HttpRequest(
    _req.method, _req.full_path, _req.data, {**_req.headers, **auth}
)
request.req = _req
```

then you can work with this new request instead of the Flask request